# How to prove this asymptotic behavior of the expectation of the maximum of the independent standard normal variables?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, integral-inequality

How to prove this famous theorem?
If $G_1,G_2,...,G_n$ are independent standard normal random variables($\mathcal{N}(0,1)$), then:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\mathbb{E}[\max_{i=1,2,...,n}G_i]}{\sqrt{2\log n}}=1$$
I know the first step:
$\Psi_G(\lambda)=\mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda G}]=\frac{\lambda^2}{2}$ then according to the Jensen's inequality, for all $\lambda>0$
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\exp(\lambda\mathbb{E}[\max_{i=1,2,...,n}G_i]&\leq\mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda\max_{i=1,2,...,n}G_i)]\\
&=\mathbb{E}[\max_{i=1,2,...,n}\exp(\lambda G_i)]\\
&\leq \sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}[\exp(\lambda G_i)]\leq ne^{\frac{\lambda^2}{2}}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
then $$\mathbb{E}[\max_{i=1,2,...,n}G_i]\leq\frac{\log n}{\lambda}+\frac{\lambda}{2}$$
the right term is minimised with $\lambda=\sqrt{2\log n}$ we have $$\mathbb{E}[\max_{i=1,2,...,n}G_i]\leq\sqrt{2\log n}$$
What's the next step?

Comment: It is a Corollary of Theorem 3 of [arXiv:1511.02176](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.02176).